# Product Page Layout After Seaching

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, page-layouts

I have an issue in Magento 1.9.

If I click on a product in the category page the product page loads fine with the 3 column layout. Great.

But if I search for the same product using the search box the layout on the product page changes to 2-column right.

I've got the layout set to apply to products in the admin panel
[image: Admin Panel]

This is the product page after I click the product in the category page
[image: Correct Layout]

This is the product page layout after clicking on the product on the search page
[image: Incorrect layout after search]

Comment: check the catalog.xml  
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

Comment: @RahulSingh Should be added as an answer ;)

Comment: @sv3n Yeah added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the setTemplate in catalog.xml (your theme layout folder)

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label"> 
   <reference name="root"> 
     <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action> 
   </reference>
...
...
...
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: oops, i thought on search list the design changed, let me edit the answer